# OpenLayers OpenStreetMap OSM not rendered

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to render a part of OpenStreetMap offline, previously loaded as map.osm (OSM XML). I'm starting a localhost and loading the xml from disk.

I tried to use similar example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-osm.html) changing only the source to my file, yet this didn't work out. Data loaded is pretty much similar to data I see in the example.

I tried a bunch of various approaches, and I still can't render the map. I get no errors, and I can't get what I'm missing.

```
var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
   format: new OSMXML()
 });

 var xml = await fetch('map.osm').then(res => res.text());

 var features = (new OSMXML()).readFeatures(xml);
 // Features are parsed OK
 vectorSource.addFeatures(features);

 var vector = new VectorLayer({
   source: vectorSource,
   // Using styles, I don't post them here (a lot of code)
   style: function (feature) {
     for (var key in styles) {
       var value = feature.get(key);
       if (value !== undefined) {
         for (var regexp in styles[key]) {
           if (new RegExp(regexp).test(value)) {
             return styles[key][regexp];
           }
         }
       }
     }
     return null;
   }
 });
 map = new Map({
   layers: [vector],
   target: document.getElementById('map'),
   view: new View({
     center: [0, 0],
     maxZoom: 0,
     zoom: 0
   })
 });
```

Comment: If the data is similar to the example you will need `.readFeatures(xml, { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })`

Comment: @Mike Similar to example - I mean, it looks similar xml, values are different though. I tried to do this, yet didn't work out

Comment: Try using `console.log(xml);` and `console.log(features);` to make sure the data has been loaded as expected and parsed correctly.  If that shows you have features comment out the style function in case there is a problem with your styles you should see features in the OpenLayers default blue style.

Comment: @Mike as I already mentioned, features are parsed correctly. I removed styling and this still doesn't work

Comment: It would still be worthwhile confirming exactly what has been parsed - and if there are features then confirm the transformed geometry `features.forEach(function(feature){console.log(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates())});`

Comment: @Mike three times I said - they are parsed TOTALLY CORRECT

Comment: If there was no problem with the features and no problem with the style (and even if there was a problem with your style the default style would work) you would see the features on the map.